# Salesforce Managed Package Usage Metrics on Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, usagemetrics

I have an application on the Salesforce app exchange for which I would like to gather usage metrics (i.e. how much/many users using the application when downloaded in their org).

Seems like we can only get metrics on VF Pages and Custom Objects as per this article (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/usage_metrics_intro.htm).

How can we get similar usage metrics on Aura Lightning Components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Appexchange Analytics](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.224.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_intro.htm) feature for this. You will need to be an ISV application partner with salesforce to get this feature activated.

The custom Object [Usage log files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/app_analytics_custom_object_logs.htm) will have fields for Lightning Components.Filter on `custom_entity_type` field from the logs.

For Technical Details on how to use Appexchange Analytics please check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/276672/what-are-the-correct-steps-to-get-data-back-from-an-appanalyticsqueryrequest/277853) question.

Comment: Thanks, Mohith. This is really helpful. I will get started with creating a case with SF to enable this.